# Number of independant paths between a discrete set of points?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, polya-counting-theory

How can we calculate the total number of paths joining any pair of points in a collection of $N$ points?

Specifically, consider the following example of a set of four points (their distribution on a square is not important) :

[image]

Now we could join any pair of these 4 points like these (I don't think I missed some paths):

[image]

For three points only, there are 6 paths.

Crossing of lines is permited.  A path shouldn't come back to the start point.  For a set of 4 points, I found 30 paths possible.  But what should be the formula for a set of $N$ points ?

Answer (score 3):

So, you are picking $k-$vertices out of $n$ and then forming a path on them, so you have to give them an ordering in which the path is gonna pass. Notice that this creates a symmetry (do i go on the path forwards or backwards). The formula, then, should be
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum _{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}k!$$

Comment: Is there a chance that this sum could give a simple analytical formula?

Comment: Also, maybe an approximate formula could be given for very large integer $n$ ?

Comment: Note $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}k!=n!(1+1+\frac12+\ldots+\frac1{n!})=\lfloor en!\rfloor$

Comment: @Cham Analytical in $n$? It is a polynomial on $n.$ but Empy2 comment is good for computation. For more info, check: https://oeis.org/A038155